# What does Hume's Fork teach us about pattern recognition?

Tags: consciousness, cognitive-psychology

I could be wrong but I think that pattern recognition means mastering mental schema to predict the future.

Hume's fork is a brand new concept that I learned about and offers an interesting perspective about relations of ideas and matters of fact.

Does it make sense that continuity of events, contrast, and change (causality) the main elements of pattern recognition? Do you perhaps think that I am reading too much into these concepts?

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: Hume's fork implies that examination of past events does not logically entail anything about the future. Since we are, nonetheless, successful at predicting some aspects of the future in practice something weaker than logical entailment must favor it, something beyond mere relations of ideas. Mill later called it "uniformity of nature", and continuity and causality are vaguely specified aspects of it. Kant tried to make them more specific as his synthetic *a priori*, and, in a fallible and relativized form, they can be said to underlie "pattern recognition" in science.

Comment: Pattern recognition is mainly done using neuro-network connection or other machine learning models (such as SVM, genetic evolution, Bayes, etc) as error-correction learning process which hinted our basic perception of matters of fact is ultimately caused from some reasoning not experience. In a word, no reasoning  no experience...